# How to Select and Use a Digitally Signed Certificate From a Client?

Tags: 2010, office-integration, digital-signature

Hi there:

I have the next question, how can a customer sign an XML, Word document or workflow directly from SharePoint using his/her personal signature?

The digital signature **is on the client side** so I don't know how to ask the client to select a signature.  Maybe I should use an ActiveX control?.

I tried using the workflow to collect signatures, but it does not sign the document (even when I put a sign line inside the document).

Example of Digital Sign Selection:
[image: Example of Digital Sign Selection]

Apparently, and AFAIK, it is only possible in SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) and Office 2007.

Comment: Are these signatures (like your name) or digitally signed certificates?

Comment: digital signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CoSign Connector for SharePoint](http://www.arx.com/digital-signature/sharepoint) integrates with SharePoint and enables server-side digital signing of documents from the SharePoint web user interface.

Signing actions may also be included in workflows. No more print/sign/scan steps.

Disclosure: I work for CoSign.

Comment: Thanks, however i finally dropped the project because the lack of clear requirements, too much work, and so little time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Our company, K2C Solutions, has a set of features that enable both Electronic Signature and Digital Signature.

The signature actions can be added at any step of a SharePoint Designer or Nintex workflow, you can have a look at http://www.k2c.com.

Hope this help